# Is it possible to have a function that returns true if my iOS application is currently in the foreground (active)? (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know that and use that function in a view controller, if possible.

Comment: why did I get a negative point for that question? :(

Comment: Because is a question that would be easily answered by reading the documentation about background execution.

Comment: allright, fair enough

Comment: We're here to help, but asking for help (in general, no only online) should be your last resort, once you've gone through the Docs and Google and found nothing. Learning how to search will make you a better programmer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIApplication`'s `applicationState` property.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/applicationState)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a property to true in `applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)` and pass that property to a view controller, or you could make your view controller an observer with `NSNotificationCenter` using the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` for a method you pass to a selector.

Edit:

You could put this in your view controller

```
// In viewDidLoad
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("mySpecialFunction:"), name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

// Your custom function
func mySpecialFunction() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: this actually works, but it is in Appdelegate...is there a way to cal that from a view controller?